# Mapping: Can we use something in lieu of the conditional operator

Tags: perl

So, I understand what the following code does and why it works, but it seems like there should be a different way to do this:

```
my @squares = map { $_ > 5 ? ($_ * $_) : () } @numbers;
```

Is there a way that we can essentially say:

```
my @squares = map { if ($_ > 5) then ($_ * $_) } @numbers;
```

Or do we have to have "rule" for every entry, ie else return ()?

Comment: `EXPR?EXPR:EXPR` is called the *conditional operator*. It's not *the* ternary operator; it's merely *a* ternary operator among others. Fixed title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

amon gave you lots of info, but didn't actually answer the question. The equivalent of

```
map { $_ > 5 ? ($_ * $_) : () }
```

using `if` instead of the conditional operator is

```
map { if ($_ > 5) { $_ * $_ } else { () } }
```

It's impossible for the map expression not to return a value. It returns the last expression evaluated. If you remove the `else` clause, that expression is the comparison, so it would similar to if you did

```
map { if ($_ > 5) { $_ * $_ } else { $_ > 5 } }
```

though `$_ > 5` only gets executed once, so I guess it's closer to

```
map { ($_ > 5) && ($_ * $_) }
```

So yes, you do have to have a rule for every entry, in the sense that it's impossible not to.

Answer (score 5):

For this to work, the `map` block *has* to return the empty list for unwanted items. While the code yould be rewritten with `grep`,

```
my @squares = map { $_**2 } grep { $_ > 5 } @numbers;
```

this looses a lot of elegance.

If we do not specify an `else` return value, the `if` seems to implicitly pass on the false value:

```
say $_+0 for map{ if($_>5){$_**2} } 3..7;
# 0
# 0
# 0
# 36
# 49
```

which is useless for our purpose.

But we can always write a filtering map that returns the value of our block, or the empty list if it was false:

```
sub mapgrep (&@) {
  my $cb = shift;
  map { local $_ = $_; $cb->($_) || () } @_;
}

my @squares = mapgrep { $_**2 if $_ > 5 } @numbers;
```

However, this relies on the side effect that a conditional returns the value of the condition if this state is not otherwise handled. I can't see where this is explicitly documented.

(Note: Perl does not have a keyword `then`).

Comment: Thanks.  I know there's no `then`, I was using pseudo-code.  Just wondering, if I wrote the above subroutine, I would just write: `sub mapgrep` instead of `sub mapgrep (&@)`.  Is what I'm doing looked down upon?

Comment: @SteveP. For most purposes, prototypes are evil. They change the way the sub invocation is parsed, and are primarily meant to impose context on the arguments, often leading to unexpected behaviour. However, the `&@` allows us to write a `map`-like subroutine by emitting `sub` from the block. Without the prototype, it would have been `mapgrep sub { ... }, @numbers`.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing: when I looked at `my @squares = map { $_**2 } grep { $_ > 5 } @numbers;`, I originally thought it should be written as: `my @squares = grep { $_ > 5 } map { $_**2 }  @numbers;`. I kinda rationalized why your way is correct, but I tried to switch the order anyway to see what would happen.  For `my @numbers = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);`, the output was "unexpected": `9 16 ... 81` What's going on here?

Comment: @Steve P.: The value of `$_` in the `grep` or `map` block refers to each input in turn to the block, which comes from the list on its immediate right. So if you swap the order, the `grep { $_ > 5 }` is filtering the already-squared numbers. 9 is the first square number over 5.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you both.